# Create QuestionManagement class

Tags: magento2, api, massaction, repository, interface

I have made Question repository class:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Vendor\Module\Api\QuestionRepositoryInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Api\Data\QuestionInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Api\Data\QuestionInterfaceFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Api\Data\QuestionSearchResultsInterfaceFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Questions as ResourceData;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Questions\CollectionFactory as QuestionCollectionFactory;

class QuestionRepository implements QuestionRepositoryInterface
{

protected $_instances = [];

protected $_resource;

protected $_questionCollectionFactory;

protected $_searchResultsFactory;

protected $_questionInterfaceFactory;

protected $_dataObjectHelper;

public function __construct(
    ResourceData $resource,
    QuestionCollectionFactory $questionCollectionFactory,
    QuestionSearchResultsInterfaceFactory $questionSearchResultsInterfaceFactory,
    QuestionInterfaceFactory $questionInterfaceFactory,
    DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->_questionCollectionFactory = $questionCollectionFactory;
    $this->_searchResultsFactory = $questionSearchResultsInterfaceFactory;
    $this->_questionInterfaceFactory = $questionInterfaceFactory;
    $this->_dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
}

/**
 * @param QuestionInterface $data
 * @return QuestionInterface
 * @throws CouldNotSaveException
 */
public function save(QuestionInterface $data)
{
    try {
        /** @var QuestionInterface|\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $data */
        $this->_resource->save($data);
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(__(
            'Could not save the data: %1',
            $exception->getMessage()
        ));
    }
    return $data;
}

/**
 * Get data record
 *
 * @param $dataId
 * @return mixed
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getById($dataId)
{
    if (!isset($this->_instances[$dataId])) {
        /** @var \Magebit\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionInterface|\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $data */
        $data = $this->_questionInterfaceFactory->create();
        $this->_resource->load($data, $dataId);
        if (!$data->getId()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Requested data doesn\'t exist'));
        }
        $this->_instances[$dataId] = $data;
    }
    return $this->_instances[$dataId];
}

/**
 * @param SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria
 * @return \Magebit\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionSearchResultsInterface
 */
public function getList(SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
{
    /** @var \Magebit\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionSearchResultsInterface $searchResults */
    $searchResults = $this->_searchResultsFactory->create();
    $searchResults->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);

    /** @var \Magebit\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Questions\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->_questionCollectionFactory->create();

    //Add filters from root filter group to the collection
    /** @var FilterGroup $group */
    foreach ($searchCriteria->getFilterGroups() as $group) {
        $this->addFilterGroupToCollection($group, $collection);
    }
    $sortOrders = $searchCriteria->getSortOrders();
    /** @var SortOrder $sortOrder */
    if ($sortOrders) {
        foreach ($searchCriteria->getSortOrders() as $sortOrder) {
            $field = $sortOrder->getField();
            $collection->addOrder(
                $field,
                ($sortOrder->getDirection() == SortOrder::SORT_ASC) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC'
            );
        }
    } else {
        $field = 'data_id';
        $collection->addOrder($field, 'ASC');
    }
    $collection->setCurPage($searchCriteria->getCurrentPage());
    $collection->setPageSize($searchCriteria->getPageSize());

    $data = [];
    foreach ($collection as $datum) {
        $dataDataObject = $this->_questionInterfaceFactory->create();
        $this->_dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray($dataDataObject, $datum->getData(), QuestionInterface::class);
        $data[] = $dataDataObject;
    }
    $searchResults->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());
    return $searchResults->setItems($data);
}

/**
 * @param QuestionInterface $data
 * @return bool
 * @throws CouldNotSaveException
 * @throws StateException
 */
public function delete(QuestionInterface $data)
{
    /** @var \Magebit\Faq\Api\Data\QuestionInterface|\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $data */
    $id = $data->getId();
    try {
        unset($this->_instances[$id]);
        $this->_resource->delete($data);
    } catch (ValidatorException $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(__($e->getMessage()));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new StateException(
            __('Unable to remove data %1', $id)
        );
    }
    unset($this->_instances[$id]);
    return true;
}

/**
 * @param $dataId
 * @return bool
 * @throws CouldNotSaveException
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 * @throws StateException
 */
public function deleteById($dataId)
{
    $data = $this->getById($dataId);
    return $this->delete($data);
}
}
```

QuestionManagement.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Vendor\Module\Api\QuestionManagementInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Api\QuestionRepositoryInterface;

class QuestionManagement implements QuestionManagementInterface
{
protected $questionRepository;

public function __construct
(
    QuestionRepositoryInterface $questionRepository
)
{
    $this->questionRepository = $questionRepository;
}

public function disableQuestion()
{

}

public function enableQuestion()
{

}
}
```

Can someone help me to write an implementation of disableQuestion() and enableQuestion() methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way to enable/disable. Guess, question enable/disable column name is **status**.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Vendor\Module\Api\QuestionManagementInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Api\QuestionRepositoryInterface;

class QuestionManagement implements QuestionManagementInterface
{
    protected $questionRepository;

    public function __construct
    (
        QuestionRepositoryInterface $questionRepository
    )
    {
        $this->questionRepository = $questionRepository;
    }

    public function disableQuestion($id)
    {
        $question = $this->questionRepository->getById($id);
        $question->setStatus(0);
        $this->questionRepository->save($question);
    }

    public function enableQuestion($id)
    {
        $question = $this->questionRepository->getById($id);
        $question->setStatus(1);
        $this->questionRepository->save($question);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function setQuestionStatus($question, $status)
{
    //this allows you to pass an id or a question object to the method
    //if the id is not found in the db, a NoSuchEntity exception will be twrown.
    if (is_int($question)) {
        $question = $this->questionRepository->getById($question);
    }
    $question->setIsActive($status); // method `setIsActive` may be different. depends on how your db field is called
    $this->questionRepository->save($question);
}

public function disableQuestion($question)
{
    $this->setQuestionStatus($question, 0);
}

public function enableQuestion()
{
    $this->setQuestionStatus($question, 1);
}
```